# Any way to prevent Mozilla from searching the web when you make a typo in a URL?

Tags: url, firefox, search, mozilla

When I type a long URL into Mozilla Firefox's address line, I sometimes make a typing mistake.  Sometimes that mistake is in the DNS name of the site.  When this happens, or whenever Firefox does not recognize the DNS name, it turns the address line into a search of Google.  I find this incredibly annoying.  If it left it there, and just said it can't find the server, I might be able to go back and change the one character that was bad.  Instead, everything I typed is wiped out, and I have to type the entire address again from the beginning.

Is there any way to disable this annoying behavior?  I *never* want it to do a google search of what I type in the address line. If I want to search google, I will go to google and do that.  I can't find the configuration switch to just leave what I typed there instead of clearing it and replacing it with something else.

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://superuser.com though you should read their guideline before posting their.

Comment: Ps it can be disabled in *about:config* : `keyword.enabled` https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-web-address-bar#w_turning-off-the-web-search-in-the-address-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer suggested by Kaiido worked.  There is a preference that can be turned off:

- In the address bar, type `about:config` and press `Enter`.
- The about:config "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click I accept the risk! to continue to the about:config page.
- In the Search field, type `keyword.enabled`.
- Double-click the keyword.enabled preference to set its value to `false`.

Thanks!